# Start a time on a click

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am building a simple angular app. I have a button that when clicking I would like it to start a timer. I had all of this working until I moved my html into directives and the timer stopped working.

My timer is a seperate file called timer.js

directive with the button.

```
angular.module('DraftBoard').directive('draftPlayer', function(){
return {

    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/draftPlayer.html',

    };
});
```

directive with the timer

```
angular.module('DraftBoard').directive('teamInfo', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/teamInfo.html'
};


});
```

So how do I make the button work?

in case more code is needed
[github](https://github.com/jminterwebs/DraftBoard)

and a current working demo

[Demo](https://calm-river-5095.herokuapp.com/)

Sorry if I left no where enough info. I am stumped with this one.

Comment: Can you create a plunker demo?

Comment: stick it in a service. then you can inject it wherever necessary